# Linux Ethernet Bridge (bridge-utils) does not reply to ARP requests

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, bridge, esxi

I am having problems with a newly created Linux bridge. The architecture is:

```
PC1 (eth0)   <--->   (eth2) BridgePC (eth0)   <--->   (eth0) PC2
```

BridgePC is a virtual machine (ESXi Hypervisor).
Bridge `br0` is up and running. DHCP broadcasts are forwarded from PC2’s segment via BridgePC to PC1. So PC1 is supplied with an IP address from the DHCP Server on PC2’s side.

`brctl showmacs br0` verifies that PC1 and PC2’s and other MACs are learned on the bridge.

The problem is when trying to ping PC1 (unicast message) from PC2 a `tshark -f 'arp'` on BridgePC verifies that PC2 sends ARP requests to determine PC1’s MAC for the `ping` command. But BridgePC neither forwards the ARP request to PC1 nor does it respond with a ProxyARP (on behalf of PC1).

I know that ProxyArp may be configured separately, but none of the bridging tutorials I found mention to do that explicitly.

Here is the kernel IP routing table:

```
Destination   Gateway       Genmask           Flags  Metric  Ref  Use Iface
default       192.168.0.1   0.0.0.0           UG     0       0      0 eth0
192.168.0.0   *             255.255.255.0     U      0       0      0 br0
192.168.0.1   *             255.255.255.255   UH     0       0      0 eth0
```

Comment: Can you post the routing tables?

Comment: updated in post

Comment: This is really Ethernet, right? No wireless or other things involved?

Comment: yes, 2 ethernet NICs in a virtual machine (ESXI Hypervisor)